# String passed into cursor.callproc becomes unknown (psycopg2, python 2.7, postgres 9.3)

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

For some reason, passing a string from Python into a Postgres function and calling it using a psycopg2 cursor causes the function to be unrecognized because the argument is unknown.

The function is very simple like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION text_test (some_text text)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

On the python side, I have:

```
cursor.callproc("text_test", ("test",))
```

And I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: function text_test(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM text_test('test')
                      ^
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Why does this only happen with strings and what do I need to do to have a function successfully accept a string? For some reason numeric data types are unaffected by this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because there is no way to cast the string to the "correct" text type. Is it a `char(N)`? A `varchar(N)`? A `text`?

Unfortunately `.callproc()` doesn't provide an easy way to specify the argument types but you can always use `.execute()` casting the arguments explicitly and everything works:

```
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM text_test(%s::text)", ("test",))
```

Comment: This is the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You could also make a list with the parameters you need to send:

```
param_list = ["test"]
curs.callproc(proc_name, param_list)
```

Here is a good answer about it:
[python + psycopg2 = unknown types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267027/python-psycopg2-unknown-types)